# Is bigly a word

Tags: adverbs

Should I say 'he won big'
or 'he won bigly'

meaning is big both an adjective and an adverb?

Comment: Did you check a dictionary? If so, what did you find?

Comment: Did you do any research at all? What is your opinion based on your research?

Comment: This word is often attributed to Donald Trump, but it is believed that he is actually saying "big league" (with a slight slur, perhaps), which is a baseball reference:  https://www.nytimes.com/2016/10/25/us/politics/trump-bigly-big-league-linguists.html?mcubz=3

Comment: Yes I did some research and found some answers that were contradicting to me.When I first heard the president use bigly it did sound awkward to me but ending as many adverbs with -ly I found it correct but due to many comments in the media I thought about it and compared with words as fast/fastly, hard/hardly and others. It may be correct to use bigly although it doesn't sound right to me. English is my second language. I am just interested in the English language but maybe this is not the right place for me. In that case I will not disturb you anymore

Comment: @Frank I think it is technically correct in line with the adverbial definitions listed, but because 'bigly' has fallen out of use today, people were surprised.

Answer (score 1):

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bigly) lists the definition as:

> **adverb**
>
> 1. in a big way; greatly
> 2. strongly; with violent force
> 3. boastfully; haughtily
>
> **adjective**
>
> 4.
>   pleasantly habitable

However, I have never heard this word used in spoken or written English, and the dictionary.com page also remarks:

> [The word 'bigly'] never quite caught on in English, perhaps because the adjective big also quite adequately functions as an adverb: **to win big.**

I believe the word has also been used in certain contexts to mock one of Donald Trump's speeches:

> *“We’re not going to lose, we are going to start winning again and we’re going to **win bigly**.”*

because the usage of 'bigly' in this context sparked debate over Trump's grammatical ability.

Sources:

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bigly

http://www.independent.co.uk/news/people/donald-trump-mocked-and-derided-for-his-win-bigly-speech-on-twitter-a7012491.html

Comment: Somewhat cautious about the portion about Trump - I think it's relevant to understanding the use of the word in modern context, but I don't want to ignite political debate.

Comment: During the 2015-2016 presidential campaign, many people, myself included, thought Trump might actually intend to be saying "bigly" (although I also wondered whether it was "big league"). For what it's worth, if you search Trump's tweets (from:@realDonaldTrump) for "bigly" and for "big league" today, you'll find  no tweets in which he used "bigly," but multiple tweets using "big league," dating back to 2012. (I haven't tried to see whether he may have deleted tweets that used "bigly"). The search results are probably notable, since economy of spelling matters a lot in tweets.